# function similar to unload in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onunload

I have a file update.php in which shows a link upon execution. Clicking on that link takes you to download.php which takes a lot of time to load. I want that while that file is loading, there must be a progress bar or pop up box to tell user that downloading is in progress.

I have tried onunload event, unload function in jquery(deprecated) that do not work. Is there any other function in jquery to tell user that downloading is in progress.

Comment: try [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: There are endless ways. Here's a most basic example `window.onload = function() { $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false }); $( "#opener" ).click(function() { $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
}); };` - http://jqueryui.com/dialog/